# Cassandra mapper not handling CQLType Tuple

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax cassandra 3.1.0. I have created the following table in cassandra and inserted a record.

```
CREATE TABLE collect_things (   k int PRIMARY KEY,   v frozen <tuple <int, text, double>> );
INSERT INTO collect_things (k, v) VALUES(0, (3, 'bar', 2.1));
select * from collect_things ;
k | v
---+-----------------
 0 | (3, 'bar', 2.1)
```

When I am trying to fetch the above row in Java using Cassandra Mapper with the below code:

```
this.cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withPort(port).build();
session = cluster.connect();
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
Mapper<CollectThings> mapper = manager.mapper(CollectThings.class);
Integer  k = 0;
mapper.get(k);
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<tuple<int, varchar, double>> <-> com.datastax.driver.core.TupleType]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.get(Mapper.java:432)
```

I have the following java bean for the above table. 
CollectThings.java

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.TupleType;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Frozen;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.PartitionKey;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(keyspace = "user_info", name = "collect_things")
public class CollectThings {

    private Integer k;
    private TupleType v;

    public CollectThings() {

    }

    @PartitionKey
    public Integer getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public void setK(Integer k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Frozen
    public TupleType getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(TupleType v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
}
```

Could somebody please tell how to handle tuple types here? Does mapper out of the box not support cql tuple types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `TupleValue` instead of `TupleType`.  `TupleType` represents the type information for a particular tuple, where `TupleValue` represents an actual value.   Using your example, I was able to retrieve data by changing all references of `TupleType` to `TupleValue`.

Comment: That worked. I had in mind using TupleValue but thought TupleValue won't be able to handle all values and  represents only one value out of all wherein, it has get() method with index. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One more question please, the above is fine while fetching the data from db, but what about when I want to persist the data using mapper. How would I create a new instance of TupleValue.
My code is like : session.execute(mapper.saveQuery(bean));
But to create bean, I am not getting any way to set TupleValue v.

Comment: To create a TupleValue, you need the representative TupleType.  You can get that from Cluster.getMetadata().newTupleType(DataType.x ...);.  Then with the TupleType use newTupleValue to create a TupleValue from that TupleType.

Comment: Could you please check my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144862/cassandra-accessor-mapper-not-mapping-udt-field