# Cassandra Accessor / Mapper not mapping udt field

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax cassandra 3.1.2. I have created the following table in cassandra and inserted a record.

```
CREATE TYPE memory ( capacity text );
create TABLE laptop ( id uuid primary key, model text, ram frozen<memory> );
select * from laptop ;

 id                                   | model         | ram
--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------
 e55cba2b-0847-40d5-ad56-ae97e793dc3e | Dell Latitude | {capacity: '8gb'}
```

When I am trying to fetch the capacity field from frozen type memory in Java using Cassandra Accessor with the below code:

```
this.cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withPort(port).build();
session = cluster.connect();
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
LaptopAccessor laptopAccessor = manager.createAccessor(LaptopAccessor.class);
Result<Laptop> cp = laptopAccessor.getOne(UUID.fromString("e55cba2b-0847-40d5-ad56-ae97e793dc3e"));
System.out.println(cp.one());
```

It is giving ram datapoint itself is null.

```
id = null model = null ram = null
```

I was expecting that the mapper would create ram instance while mapping and map capacity field into it and return the Laptop bean.

I have the following Accessor interface:

```
@Accessor
interface LaptopAccessor {
   @Query("SELECT ram.capacity FROM user_info.laptop where id=?")
   Result<Laptop> getOne(UUID id);
}
```

I have the following java beans for the above table.

```
@Table(keyspace = "user_info", name = "laptop")
public class Laptop {

    private UUID id;
    private String model;
    private Memory ram;

    @PartitionKey
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }


    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Frozen
    public Memory getRam() {
        return ram;
    }


    public void setRam(Memory ram) {
        this.ram = ram;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id = " + id + " model = " + model + " ram = " + ram;
    }

}

@UDT(keyspace = "user_info", name = "memory")
public class Memory {

    private String capacity;

    @Field
    public String getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }


    public void setCapacity(String capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "capacity = " + capacity ;
    }

}
```

The code works fine when I change the query to retrieve entire ram UDT. Could somebody please tell that why the mapper doesn't work when I select some field from the udt in the query?

Doesn't cassandra support this? Any workaround to fetch the UDT fields?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the return type on your accessor:

```java
@Accessor
interface LaptopAccessor {
   @Query("SELECT ram.capacity FROM user_info.laptop where id=?")
   Result<Laptop> getOne(UUID id);
}
```

Since your query is only selecting `ram.capacity`, all the driver is getting back is a Row with a single column that is a `String` with a name of `ram.capacity` which does not map to any field in `Laptop`.

Instead, since it looks like all you want is the 1 row matching that query, you could change your `Accessor` to:

```java
@Accessor
interface LaptopAccessor {
   @Query("SELECT ram.capacity FROM user_info.laptop where id=?")
   ResultSet getOne(UUID id);
}
```

The accessor now returns a `ResultSet` for which you can call `one().getString(0)` to get the capacity back.  It's not ideal if you don't want to deal with `ResultSet` directly, but works well.

You shouldn't really need the whole `Laptop` object anyways since all you are requesting is a field of a UDT right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, my Accessor return types are generic and I have some other queries in the interface as well which returns the complete Laptop object and through my fetcher part (which is async). I always collect like Collection<T> results = results.add(future.get().one()); So, I think working directly on ResultSet would not work in my case specially in case when I have multiple such queries to return only UDT fields which have variety of data types.

Comment: I am planning to move all such fields (which I want to retrieve from udt) at table level or define a placeholder at table level (capacity) so that I can fire query like 'SELECT ram.capacity as capacity FROM user_info.laptop where id=?'

Comment: If I have the following table structure:
CREATE TABLE user_info.employees_with_address (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    complete_address list<frozen<full_address>>)
If I fetch complete_address using plain query then I need to do something like below to parse the nest List Frozen UDT.

Row r = rsf.get().one();
r.getList(r.getColumnDefinitions().getName(), CompleteAddress.class);

If I want to make it generic, then how can I fetch the type CompleteAddress.class using Definition?